# Grep. Line of text that does not end with "abcd"?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

Hi I'm looking for a regular expression for: line of text that does not end with a certain word, let's say it's "abcd"
At first I tried with
 
`.*[^abcd]$`
That one doesn't work of course. It matches a line that doesn't end with any of the letters a,b,c or d.
So, in Advanced Grep Topics, I found this expression, but couldn't get it to work:
 
`^(?>.*)(?<=abcd)`
->
`grep -e "^(?>.*)(?<=abcd)$"`

Any idea for the expression I need?

Comment: you have never accepted one answer.. you should could begin with @tobyodavies answer that is certainly correct.

Comment: grep has a _very_ basic regex engine. I sincerely doubt lookahead will work...

Comment: @toby: many versions of `grep` support PCRE with the `-P` flag

Comment: @0verbose Agreed to the first part but not to the second. `abcd$` will not return a line ending in `fooabcd` which it should according to the OP's requirements

Comment: @SiegeX . you are right. I just given you a +1 right now.

Comment: @SiegeX, I didn't parse that as being a strict requirement in the question (I read word as "sequence of chars", not "break followed by a sequence of chars"), regardless, the -v option was my point, the code was just an example

Comment: nonetheless I've edited my answer

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have a look at `grep`'s -v option

```
grep -v 'abcd$'
```

If you really meant *word* rather that just "sequence of characters" then use

```
grep -v '\babcd$'
```

`\b` meaning "word-boundary"

Comment: Why don't you need to escape the backslash? Wouldn't the shell process it shouldn't you have to write `\\b`?

Answer (score 3):

Give this a shot:

```
grep -v "\<abcd\>$"
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ printf "%s\n" "foo abcd bar baz" "foo bar baz abcd" "foo bar bazabcd" | grep -v "\<abcd\>$"
foo abcd bar baz
foo bar bazabcd
```

*Note*: This will match **whole words** as noted by the fact that the 3rd line was returned even though it contained `abcd` as the last 4 letters

Comment: Since in his first attempts the OP made no attempt to match a whole word I don't think that this is actually what he wants... Using the word "word" to mean a sequence of chars is actually more common than its true meaning in my experience...

Answer (score 2):

`grep` supports PCRE regular expressions when using `-P` flag.

One of the reason `grep -e "^(?>.*)(?<=abcd)$"` does not work is because the lookaround you are using is positive, which means totally opposite of what is required. `(?<=` is the syntax for positive lookbehind, which tells regex engine to search for lines that **ends** with `abcd`.

To search for lines that does not end with certain string, you need to use negative lookbehind. The syntax for negative lookbehind is `(?<!`. And because negative lookbehind includes exclamation mark which bash will try to interpret as an event, one can not use double quotes to supply regex to `grep`.

I used following regex to search for the lines that do not end with `log`.

```
grep -P '(?<!log)$' < <inputfile>
```

Similarly you can use above command and replace `log` with whatever pattern you want to match.

This regex can be used with other programs where inverse matching is not supported, such as `-v` option of `grep`